# Problem in data display

Tags: visualforce

i m trying to show data of custom object on standard visualforce page.
Following code not work for me. what is issue??

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
    <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockSection >
        Name:{!account.id}
     </apex:pageBlockSection>  
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with this code. Note that you must provide an ID for this code to work (e.g. `/apex/mypage?id=0010000000abcde`), the ID must be valid and you must have access to that record.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Comments like _"it doesn't work"_ aren't very helpful because, in most cases, we don't know how you _expect_ it to work. Please take some time to read [ask], and remember that (generally speaking) the more details you can include, the better. Even if you're experienced with Salesforce, when you're facing an issue, it can be hard to tell which piece of information is the key to understanding and solving your problem. The less people need to guess, the more (and better) answers you will receive.

Answer (score 1):

As you say you're trying to display data from a "Custom Object", I'm going to assume the object is not the account object because the code you've posted displays records related to the Account Object.

The first line in your code specified the standard controller as being for the "account" object. If you want to display records for "CustomObject__c" you'll need to replace "account" with "CustomObject__c" on the line below:

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
```

Further down in the code, you have the following code which displays the account name that's related to the Account.Id:

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection >
    Name:{!account.id}
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

If you want to display the record name for "CustomObject__c", you'll need to replace `Name:{!account.id}` with `Name:{!CustomObject__c.id}`.

I highly recommend you take the time to go through the [Visualforce Basics Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) in Trailhead to help you learn how to do the things you're attempting to try or at least go through the [Getting a Quick Start with Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start.htm) section of the Visualforce Developer Guide.